# Regex opposite to this match

Tags: regex, numbers, notepad++

My question is how do you regex something that is NOT what my current regex is.

My regex is: 9\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d

I'm trying to find 10 digit numbers that start with 9.
But now I want to find, those who are opposite to this.

How do i do that? I'm trying to use it with notepad++ regex, find those who are not 10 digit and doest start with 9, and delete them.

I need to delete: everything, regardless of numbers of digits as long as its not 10 digit and doesnt start with 9.

Thank you.

I have a long file that looks like this,

```
 905664572
 9055148
 9052836956
 9054950806
 9059105646
 905403434
 905654765
 9058618018
 90547214
```

where i need to get rid of all that is not 10 digit.

while using notepad++

this regex works: 9\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d

this regex doesn't: 9\d{9} AND  ^9(\d{0,9}

---

This worked to what I was trying to do:

```
 (?<!\d)[0-9](\d{0,8})
```

Comment: What version of Notepad++ are you using? It works demonstrably fine in mine.

Comment: may be you could try other tools for this

Comment: anything that works. `grep` if you on unix, python would do if you're on windows.

Comment: (?<!\d)[0-9](\d{0,8}|\d{10,})(?=\D) this worked for me :) thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is `9\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d` and could be shortened to `9\d{9}` ...

Well, the opposite could be `(?!9\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)` or `(?!9\d{9})` or `9(?>!\d{9})`

edit:
the working express: `(?<!\d)9(\d{0,8}|\d{10,})(?=\D)`

Comment: just try  `9([0-9]{0,8}|[0-9]{10})`

Comment: still no luck on notepad++ version 5.9.8

Comment: i tried this with notepad 6.2  `(?<!\d)9(\d{0,8}|\d{10,})(?=\D)`

Comment: be careful with the expression you posted at least, this would also match the first 9 digits of a valid 10 digits number

Answer (score 3):

```
^9(\d{0,8}|\d{10,})$
```

Here it is with your tests.
http://www.rubular.com/r/Ls56UCYRHa

More info on Regular Expressions http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: according to this http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions it should work, but it doesn't work in my NPP either oddly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
^9(\d{0,8}|\d{10,})$
```

this ensures that your input starts with a `9` and is followed by any number of digits except nine.

Comment: I guess i'll be using this ^9(\d{0,9} because i need 9 on the rest.