# How to get the opposite matches of a given regex

Tags: regex, string

Given a string of values which are double pipe separated, I would like to match all values which do not start with a given sequence of characters.

For example, given `blue||green||blue stone||` and given the *non* matching sequence `blue`, I would like to get the following match: `green||`.

Using the regex `blue[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[|][|]` I can match the two entries with `blue` in them, but how can I negate this to get the opposite result? I've tred: `(?!blue[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[|][|])` but that returns 24 empty matches (tested on regex101.com).

An additional problem is that I have to use a language in which I need the result within a single statement, as the private 3rd party language is very restrictive.

I've also gone over some examples I've found in other Stackoverflow questions, unfortunately however, none have helped to resolve my issue, examples:

[Regex Match Inverse/Opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881638/regex-match-inverse-opposite)
[Regex opposite to this match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087009/regex-opposite-to-this-match)

Comment: What is that language called? What flavor does it use?

Comment: Something like this: `(?<=blue\|\|)([^|]*\|\|)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5Na39/1)

Comment: @InSync, it's a proprietary language in a niche market - it's similar to Excel formulae, and which flavor? Regex flavor? I'm not sure.

Comment: @dawg, within regex101 that worked perfectly, thank you.
If you provide that as the answer with a little detail/explaination, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: If your language does not have lookbehinds (and most simple re languages do not) you can use a sacrificial match: `\bblue\|\|([^|]*\|\|)`

Comment: Jusrt `split` with the pattern, and you will get the items you need. If there is always a single match, you may want to use a regex `replace` method. With PCRE, you might get away with https://regex101.com/r/HA7zYr/1.

Comment: If the language supports lookarounds: [`(?<=^|\|\|)(?!blue)[^|]+\|\|`](https://regex101.com/r/cUeEMy/1). A more refined answer would require more information on the language and its capabilities.

Comment: It depends on the regex engine used check this [Demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/en/regex-tester/5a1ca147df31)